# Прошу проверить правильность кода

Tags: python, numpy, cuda

Дано задание: "Необходимо реализовать программу параллельного вычисления суммы двух одномерных массивов с 1млн значений в каждом"
Необходимо реализовать на CuPy
Я изучаю Python только 1 семестр и многого не понимаю. Прошу проверить написанный мною код. Выполняю ли я условия задания?

Код:

```
import cupy as cp
### CuPy and GPU
x_gpu = cp.ndarray((1,1000000))
x_gpu += x_gpu
cp.cuda.Stream.null.synchronize()
print(x_gpu)
```

Comment: я ничего не знаю про cupy, но где у вас **два** массива?

Comment: Разве они не создаются третьей строчкой «cp.ndarray…”

Comment: Прошу меня направить, могу сильно ошибаться. Изучения пайтон очень плохо даётся для меня в ВУЗе

Comment: Эта строка создаёт одномерный массив float длиной 1000000

Comment: Это значит ,что в нём один миллион элементов?

Comment: Значит нужно добавить аналогичную строчку для второго массива?

Comment: Насколько я понял, это всё можно реализовать с numpy, а потом изменить numpy на cupy

Comment: Из задания непонятно, откуда должны браться массивы. Из файла? Или нужно сгенерить случайные (или не случайные) числа?

Comment: Кстати, вы создаёте двумерный массив, только у него первое измерение размером 1, так что тут тоже неправильно. Второе то измерение размером миллион. Но требуется создать всё же одномерный массив.

Comment: И в задаче еще сказано, что это должна быть программа для "параллельного" вычисления. Я бы это понял как то, что работу надо разделить на несколько потоков исполняющего устройства, в вашем случае GPU. Мне кажется (после 10 мин прочтения что такое вообще CUDA) что надо использовать несколько cuda.Stream, в каждом из которых будет выполняться сложение отдельного куска массивов. Если конечно cupy не умеет это как то делать "под капотом" когда вы сложение пишите

Comment: @Mike Скорее всего да, это как-то само делается, как и в numpy - просто складываются два массива и всё. Но, конечно, маловато у нас в целом инфы по заданию.

Comment: @CrazyElf Тогда не понятно зачем в задании на этом делается акцент. Если оно само так работает и от программиста ничего не требуется для параллельности

Comment: @Mike Ну, может хотят проверить, что выполняющий задание понимает, что не нужно писать цикл на миллион итераций для того, чтобы сделать требуемое. Да, так проще - просто сложить два массива через плюсик, но для этого нужно осознание, что так вообще можно делать :)

Comment: Массив должен быть со случайными значениями, мне кажется это логично, т.к. в задании больше вообще ничего не указано и никто в вузе на этот счёт подсказать не может xD.

Comment: Как правильно записать код, чтобы массив был одномерным, с миллионом случайных значений?

Comment: @Mike читая документацию, я понял ,что всё делается аналогично как бы это делалось в numpy, но загвоздка в том ,что numpy нам преподавали очень непонятно и всего пару недель

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/1.16/reference/generated/numpy.random.random.html#numpy.random.random

Comment: @ulyanovw Просто размер указываете `1_000_000`, а не кортежем и всё. Кортеж - для многомерных размеров. Ну и берите `random` сразу, а не пустой массив создавайте.